# if else operator is not running when it should

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please check the code below. On first if section however all my conditions get false it's not going to else. Its always running the if inside codes.

To be more specific `ViewBag.gtQuickDate` this viewbag does not contain any value as shown below also other viewbags does not contain the value, then why it's not running the `else if`? Any mistake you found on operator then let me know.

```
if (ViewBag.subcattxt != "" & ViewBag.callFrom == "result" & 
     ViewBag.gtQuickDate != "2015y" || ViewBag.gtQuickDate != "2016y" || 
      ViewBag.gtQuickDate != "2017y" || ViewBag.gtQuickDate != "blank")
{


}
else if (ViewBag.subcattxt != "" & ViewBag.callFrom == "result" & 
          ViewBag.gtQuickDate == "2015y" || ViewBag.gtQuickDate == "2016y" ||
           ViewBag.gtQuickDate == "2017y" || ViewBag.gtQuickDate != "blank")
{


}
```

Comment: @GiladGreen `&` is the *non-short circuiting* operator, when provided boolean values.

Comment: No previously i used double & too the problem same. I think i am mixing things with & and || operator

Comment: Mother of god, please either use intermediate `bool` variables or an aptly named method instead of these huge conditions.

Comment: @JohnLk - add `()` around all the `||` operators

Comment: Also, break up the if clause into segments. var isNotEmptyAndIsResult, var NotInTheLastFewYears, then && them together, so the next programmer can read what's going on

Comment: You haven't said what the code is *supposed* to do. The code you've shown will always, regardless of the values of any of the variables, meet both conditions, which is probably wrong, but you haven't said what *should* happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what you're checking,if possible, could you separate ORs from ANDs, but please try:

```
  if ((!(ViewBag.subcattxt.Equals(null)) && (!(ViewBag.callFrom.Equals("result"))) && (!(ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2015y"))))
  {    
     //some other code
  }
  else if((!(ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2016y")) || (!(ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2017y")) || (!(ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("blank"))))
  {
  //some other code
  }
  else if (ViewBag.subcattxt.Equals(null) && ViewBag.callFrom.Equals("result") && ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2015y"))
  {    
     //some other code
  }
  else if(ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2016y") || ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("2017y") || ViewBag.gtQuickDate.Equals("blank"))
  {
     //other code
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the condition evaluating incorrectly is that `||` has lower precedence than `&`, so any match of `gtQuickDate` renders the entire condition true.

It is generally a very bad idea to embed the current year into code, because it stops working as expected after a set period of time, requiring a recompile.

If you are looking for `gtQuickDate` from the last three years, you can do it like this:

```
int yearNow = DateTime.Now.Date.Year;
var blankOrLastThreeYears = new[] {
    "blank"
,  $"{yearNow - 0}y"
,  $"{yearNow - 1}y"
,  $"{yearNow - 2}y"
};
```

Now your condition can be rewritten as

```
if (ViewBag.subcattxt != ""
&& ViewBag.callFrom == "result"
&& blankOrLastThreeYears.Contains(ViewBag.gtQuickDate)) {
    ...
}
```

The list in `blankOrLastThreeYears` will contain entries for the last three years, and will update automatically for 2018, 2019, and so on.